# how to use proxy for axios

Tags: axios, get, frontend, mern

im writing webapp and my frontend is running on

> http://localhost:3000

and backend is running on

> http://localhost:4000

i want use axios to do a get request on this url "http://localhost:4000/api/v1/products"

so i make a proxy in package.json file like this

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:4000"
```

and i did a get requset like this

```
const { data } = await axios.get("/api/v1/products")
```

but axios is ignore the proxy and requesting above get request from "localhost:3000"
[as show here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHSP5.png)

how can i do a get request from "localhost:4000" this url insted of "localhost:3000" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you add your proxy in the wrong file please check the proxy should add to the package.json file that belongs to your react app

Answer (score -1):

I closed my vs Code editor and reopened it and it ended up working fine for me. You might have to restart your vs Code editor.